# Run LESS mixin only once

Tags: less

I am trying to make sure a mixin that may be called several times in different files, only outputs css once.

---

## First try (less)

I first was thinking something like this:

#### mixin

```
@_mod: "false";
.mod(@_mod) when (@_mod = "false") {
    @_mod: "true";

    .mod {
        border-radius: 6px;
        border: 1px solid gray;
    }
}
```

#### call 1

```
.mod(@_mod);
```

#### call 2

```
.mod(@_mod);
```

#### output

```
.mod {
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.mod {
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

That doesn't work because the variables are namespaced and scoped to mixins.
[Read more](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2642-understanding-variable-scope-and-variable-injection-in-less-css.htm)

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/dominikwilkowski/pen/aOzgyL?editors=010)

---

## Second try (less)

I then though this:

#### mixin

```
@_mod: "false";
.mody() {
    .mody {
        border-radius: 6px;
        border: 1px solid gray;
    }
}
```

#### call 1

```
& when (@_mod = "false") {
    .mody();
}
@_mod: "true";
```

#### call 2

```
& when (@_mod = "false") {
    .mody();
}
@_mod: "true";
```

#### output

`-nothing-`

This doesn't work because of Less's lazy loading "feature" for all variables...

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/dominikwilkowski/pen/rVVeZa?editors=010)

Does anyone know a way to make sure a mixin, called multiple times, runs only once?

Comment: Apologies if I have not understood your query properly, but why would you want to call/invoke a mixin multiple times when you want it to output CSS only once?

Comment: :) a good question indeed. It's not me that is writing the code and essentially what I need is a dependency management for a poor man.

Comment: Ok, understood. This might not be the best solution (and might not even work for some of your cases) but if you can enclose the mixin calls within a dummy `&` selector/namesepace then the variable is scoped to it and so will result in only one execution. *Note:* I don't think this is a good approach.

Comment: Can you make an example? I'm not sure I'm following.

Comment: Modify your first try to be like `&{.mod(@_mod);.mod(@_mod);}`.

Comment: Thanks @Harry, the problem with this is that each call will be in different files so I can't put them into a single selector.

Comment: Do you want a LESS solution or a Sass solution?  They're completely different and a solution for one will not work for the other.

Comment: I understand that @cimmanon. I am happy with either. I am still in the scoping phase and can switch to which ever works better. I prefer LESS though ;)

Comment: No seriously, you really need to pick one because you can't accept 2 correct answers (one for each language).

Comment: There you go @cimmanon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: use [`default()`](http://lesscss.org/functions/#misc-functions-default) and make the initial mixin to expose yet another empty mixin (which will suppress the default one).

```less
// (using same name for a mixin and a ruleset is a bad idea)

._mod() when (default()) {
    ._mod() {}
    .mod {
        border-radius: 6px;
        border: 1px solid gray;
    }
}

._mod();
._mod();
._mod();
._mod();
```

Comment: Thanks for this. This works exactly how I needed it. I know it's not great to use the same naming!